# how to stop a page from relaoding after the button submit is clicked

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

when i click on my submit button,It reload the index.html.I want it to be in the same /registers page.How i can do it?

i tried redirect(url_for("registers")) but its does not work

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import csv

app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    try:

        file = open("registered.csv","r")
        reader=csv.reader(file)
        students=list(reader)
        return render_template("index.html",students=students)
    except:
        return("Fails")

@app.route("/register",methods=["post"])
def register():
    if not request.form.get("details"):
        return("fails")
    else:
        file = open("registered.csv","a")
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow((request.form.get("details")))
        file.close()
        file = open("registered.csv","r")
        reader=csv.reader(file)
        students=list(reader)
        return render_template("index.html",students=students)
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be defined in your page template, using the `action` attribute of `<form>`.

Example:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Of course, the destination url can be defined using a variable when rendering the page.

Comment: i added it still it does not work by the way i used flask not php